# python selenium not clicking on one button but clicks on another

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

So, this is a [website](http://swaid.stat.gov.pl/en/HandelZagraniczny_dashboards/Raporty_konstruowane/RAP_SWAID_HZ_3_4.aspx) i am trying to automate using selenium. But, it's not clicking on only the last two items with a plus image button in the table under the specification tab.

This is the code i tried:

```py
def fun_trade_products(trade_product):
    trade_products = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "di-cl.ewr-ca")))
    for j in trade_products:
        if j.text in trade_product:

            #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", j) 
            print(j.text, "------------------------->")
            plusclick = WebDriverWait(j, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "td")))
            sleep(2)
            #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", plusclick) 
            plusclick.click()
            sleep(3)
            return None
product_list = ['I - Live animals; animal products', 'II - Vegetable products', 'III - Fats and oils', 'IV - Prepared foodstuffs', 'V - Mineral products', 'VI - Products of the chemical industry', 'VII - Plastics and rubber and articles thereof', 'VIII - Raw hides and skins, articles thereof', 'IX - Wood and articles of wood', 'X - Pulp of wood, paper, paperboard and articles thereof', 'XI - Textiles and textile articles', 'XII - Footwear, headgear, etc.', 'XIII - Articles of stone, ceramic products, glass', 'XIV - Pearls, precious stones and metals, articles thereof', 'XV - Base metals and articles thereof', 'XVI - Machinery and mechanical appliances, electrical and electrotechnical equipment', 'XVII - Transport equipment', 'XVIII - Optical, photographic, measuring, checking instruments, etc.', 'XIX - Arms and ammunition', 'XX - Miscellaneous manufactured articles', "XXI - Works of art, collectors' pieces and antiques"]

for i in range(len(product_list)):
    fun_trade_products(product_list[i])
```

I want to click on the plus button in the website of every item in the list 'product list'.

Since, the website updates after every click, It gives me a stale element exception error sometimes, so i put the whole main code under a function and for every item in the product_list, the variable 'trade_products' gets updated and i can click on the plus button in the website.

But, my code is clicking on every plus button except only the last two ('XX - Miscellaneous manufactured articles', "XXI - Works of art, collectors' pieces and antiques") and i don't know why.

Is there anyway to click on the last two too?

Thank you and sorry if the English is not good.

Comment: button needs to be in view to click on it. uncomment execute_script() and check if it works

Comment: @DanielSabrel tried that too, it's not working. The problem is it is clicking on all the plus buttonexcept only the last two. I even tried to hard code it and still it's not clicking for only the last two items.

Comment: I tried your code and it's *not clicking on any button*, not just only last two. If you used different code and were able to click on button then the reason why you missed last two might be because they are under different element with id `#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_6b9d1cc9_04bc_403b_934a_b940ef65bd11_ctl01_ctl00_sheetContentDiv_Flow_1`. There are two element with same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to expand all the rows in [this url](http://swaid.stat.gov.pl/en/HandelZagraniczny_dashboards/Raporty_konstruowane/RAP_SWAID_HZ_3_4.aspx). Here is one way to do it.

```
# first wait till browser loads
WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ewr-nglr input[title="Expand"]')))

# loop across all expandable
while True:
    # checking if expandable/+ elements exist inside table and double clicking on parent row
    if not driver.execute_script("\
        p=document.querySelectorAll('div.ewr-nglr input[title=\"Expand\"]')[2]; \
        if (p) {return p.closest('div.di-cl.ewr-ca').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('dblclick'))} \
        else {return false}") : break
    # waiting till new data is added
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ewa-background-ready')))
    # scrolling the table; needed for some reason to avoid error
    driver.execute_script('table=document.querySelector("#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_6b9d1cc9_04bc_403b_934a_b940ef65bd11_ctl01_ctl00_sheetContentDiv"); \
        table.scrollTop=table.scrollHeight')
```

I couldn't get the click button to work so I used double click on the row. Press `Alt+DownArrow` also worked but with that approach I would had to write extra code for filtering expandable row.